# how to use default address for saving in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have model name address which allow user to create multple address and also have functionality to set the default address but i unable to fetch it for saving in models any suggestion will be a big help thank you

here is my address model choice are removed

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='address')
    reciever_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=False)
    alt_phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=state_choice, blank=False)
    pincode = models.CharField(validators = [pincodeRegex], max_length = 6, blank=False)
    eighteen = models.CharField(blank=False, choices=eighteen_choice, default='Yes', max_length=4 )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    default = models.BooleanField(("Default"), default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my views.py for seting a address to deafult

```
@login_required
def set_default_address(request, id):
    Address.objects.filter(user=request.user, default=True).update(default=False)
    Address.objects.filter(pk=id, user=request.user).update(default=True)
    return redirect('accounts:home')
```

my model in which i want to save that default address

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, default= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, default=None) 
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment and self.id:
            self.order_id = self.datetime_of_payment.strftime('COOLBUYORDER%Y%m%dODR') + str(self.id)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " " + str(self.id) + " " + str(self.created_at)
```

my views.py to fetch the address

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post (self, request,):
        user = request.user
        address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        items = Item.get_items_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
        prefer = request.POST.get('payment')

        for item in items:
            order = Order(user=user, item=item , method=prefer, **address=address.first()** ,size=cart.get(str(item.id)), price=item.price)
            
            order.save()
        request.session['cart'] = {}

        return redirect('orders:cart',)
```

instead of first address i want to save default address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do something like this:

```
address = Address.objects.filter(default=True, user=request.user)
```

Based on this you will get a `queryset` of `Address` that can't be one or zero, then in your view you can do it:

```
if not address.exists():
    # Redirect to set a default address
default_address = address.first()
```

Then in your loop add the following:

```
order = Order(user=user, item=item , method=prefer, address=default_address, size=cart.get(str(item.id)), price=item.price)
```

Of course there are many options that you can follow but this is a kind of solution that you can implement.

Comment: @Shreyash I did some changes, if you have errors doing the solution please try to add it as a details in your question.

Comment: it hrow error local variable 'default_address' referenced before assignment